# List throwing up use of unassigned local variable

Tags: c#

This is throwing up the error "use of unassigned local variable" CS0165

Why?  How do I fix it?

```
List<tag> TagList;
TagList.Insert(TagNo + 1,importWire);
```

Comment: `List<tag> TagList = new List<tag>();`

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y7h161d.aspx

Comment: The solution would be to assign the local variable.

Answer (score 1):

First create a new instance of the list:

```
List<tag> TagList = new List<tag>();
//do stuff with the list
```